# Filtrar elementos en blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-9

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
$betterVotedObjects = ObjectUser::with(['object'])
    ->orderBy('count_times', 'desc')
    ->limit(5)
    ->get();
```

Este objeto me trae datos de una tabla, y de hecho lo hace bien.

dentro de los datos que trae , cada dato esta asociado a una categoria. Lo que quiero, en blade, por ejemplo extraer los elementos que son de una categoría determinada para mostrar en alguna o algunas partes de la pagina.

Siendo mas especificos, hay 4 categorías de datos, y la consulta me trae todos los datos con sus respectivas categorias, entonces, en una parte de la pagina quiero que mostrar unicamente los de la categoria1, en otra parte de la misma pagina quiero mostrar solo los de la categoria2, en un widget lateral quiero mostrar solo los de la categoria3, etc.

Por esto quiero filtrar la colección desde blade en lugar de hacer tres consultas o mas a la base de datos.

gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se ha utilizado la directiva @foreach de Blade en un archivo de vista de Laravel para filtrar y mostrar elementos de una colección en diferentes partes de la página según su categoría. Para lograr esto, se ha aplicado una condición @if dentro de cada bucle @foreach, verificando el valor del campo "category" de cada objeto en la colección. Así, se logra mostrar solo los elementos de la categoría deseada en cada sección específica de la página, evitando la necesidad de realizar múltiples consultas a la base de datos y optimizando la presentación de los datos.

```
{{-- Mostrar elementos de la categoría 1 --}}
@foreach ($betterVotedObjects as $object)
    @if ($object->category === 'categoria1')
        {{-- Aquí coloca el código HTML para mostrar el objeto --}}
    @endif
@endforeach

{{-- Mostrar elementos de la categoría 2 --}}
@foreach ($betterVotedObjects as $object)
    @if ($object->category === 'categoria2')
        {{-- Aquí coloca el código HTML para mostrar el objeto --}}
    @endif
@endforeach

{{-- Mostrar elementos de la categoría 3 en un widget lateral --}}
<div class="widget">
    @foreach ($betterVotedObjects as $object)
        @if ($object->category === 'categoria3')
            {{-- Aquí coloca el código HTML para mostrar el objeto en el widget --}}
        @endif
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Reemplaza 'categoria1', 'categoria2' y 'categoria3' con los valores reales que representan las categorías en tu colección.

Como te he respondido a la pregunta, por favor, marque la respuesta como válida

Comment: Excelente, en el pasado lo habia hecho asi y la verdad hoy me habia bloqueado. Claro es preciso lo que necesitaba. Gracias